# Sql script syntax and grammar issues

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can someone help please I dont know what I am doing wrong:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  name
        FROM    sys.tables
        WHERE   name = N'MemberIdsToDelete' ) 
DROP TABLE [MemberIdsToDelete];
GO

SELECT  mm.memberid ,
        mm.aspnetuserid ,
        mm.email ,
        mm.RowNum AS RowNum
INTO    #MemberIdsToDelete
FROM    membership.members AS mm
        LEFT JOIN aspnet_membership AS asp ON mm.aspnetuserid = asp.userid
        LEFT JOIN trade.tradesmen AS tr ON tr.memberid = mm.memberid
WHERE   asp.isapproved = 0
        AND tr.ImportDPN IS NOT NULL
    AND tr.importDPN <> ''
ORDER BY mm.memberid

DECLARE @MaxRownum INT
SET @MaxRownum = ( SELECT   MAX(RowNum)
                   FROM     #MemberIdsToDelete
                 )

DECLARE @Iter INT
SET @Iter = ( SELECT    MIN(RowNum)
              FROM      #MemberIdsToDelete
            )

DECLARE @MemberId INT
DECLARE @TrademId INT
DECLARE @UId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @Successful INT
DECLARE @OutputMessage VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @Email VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Username VARCHAR(100)

SELECT  @MemberId = memberId ,
        @UId = AspNetUserId
FROM    MemberIdsToDelete
SELECT  @TrademId = TradesManId
FROM    trade.TradesMen
WHERE   memberId = @MemberId;

WHILE @Iter <= @MaxRownum 
  BEGIN
    SELECT  *
    FROM    #MemberIdsToDelete
    WHERE   RowNum = @Iter
  --more code here
    SET @Iter = @Iter + 1
  END
```

I just want to check if my table MemberIdsToDelete exists, if so drop it,
create MemberIdsToDelete with the results set from the select
loop through MemberIdsToDelete table and perform operations

I am getting error that RowNum does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, to check if a table exists and then drop accordingly, you need to use something like

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name 
           FROM sys.tables 
           WHERE name = N'MemberIdsToDelete') 
DROP TABLE [MemberIdsToDelete];
GO
```

as for the error, your RowNum column does not exist when you are attempting to reference it. Include it in the SELECT statement

```
select mm.memberid, mm.aspnetuserid, mm.email, mm.RowNum AS RowNum    
into #MemberIdsToDelete     
from membership.members as mm      
    left join aspnet_membership as asp       
        on mm.aspnetuserid=asp.userid       
            left join trade.tradesmen as tr       
                on tr.memberid=mm.memberid       
where asp.isapproved = 0 and tr.ImportDPN IS NOT NULL 
    and tr.importDPN <> '' 
order by mm.memberid;
GO
```

I hope this helps.

*Edit. Based on you additional error from your comment. You are now attempting to access a temporary table that does not exist. You must first populate the temporary table `#MemberIdsToDelete` before attempting to read from it. The invalid column error is down to the same problem. You are attempting to read a column called `RowNum` from the temporary table which does not exist.*

*Edit2. Remove the '#' from the `#MemberIdsToDelete`. You are inserting into a table not a temporary table. Or, Add a # to the `select into` above (see the code above). This will make it a temporary table as required.*

Comment: i still get en errors: Invalid column name 'RowNum'. and Invalid object name '#MemberIdsToDelete' with regards to the if exists, yikes i know MySql backwards but sql is another story :)

Comment: thanks, so in order to create the temp table i can just run the select? which i tried and still got error invalid column name "RowNum'

Comment: thanks but still complaining about the rownum as invalid columnname..I added a # to "into #MemberIdsToDelete". Seeing that it is a temp table now one should be able to add a user column?

Comment: in the: "select mm.memberid, mm.aspnetuserid, mm.email, mm.RowNum AS RowNum " line

Comment: Dude, the select statement I wrote, shows _an example_ of how you select the RowNum into your temporary table. You need to ensure that there is actually a table called RowNum in the database `membership.members`. If there isn't one, you can't expect to select it...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a RowNum column in that table.

Try:

select mm.memberid, mm.aspnetuserid, mm.email, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as RowNum
....

This should solve your problem, but I wouldnt actually recommend this idea of looping through the ones to delete.